# How to call control on a Panel that is inside usercontrol

Tags: c#, button, controls, panel

i'm trying to solve this, with no sucess.

I'm building a code that needs to acess some controls, those are Inside of usercontrol and inside A panel.
the thing is, i have more than thousand of buttons, it's madness to do this at hand, the line counts will be insanly high.

That said, i managed to build a method to do this, but i have one obstacle that i cant get rid of:

```
this.usercontrol.panel1.Controls[buttoninsidepanel].InvokeRequired
```

I have alot of panels too, each panel has it's own buttons.

i Don't know how to create a "variable" that will act as the "panel1" in the example.

i tried :

```
usercontrol.Controls[panel].Controls[buttoninsidepanel].Invoke
```

where [panel] refeers to a string that receive the name of the panel that i want to get the control.

it throws :" Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Any way to replace the panel name with a variable that i can change dynamically, the same way i'm doing with the buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_) method like this:

`((Panel) usercontrol.Controls.Find("panel1",true)[0])`

Comment: Can you elucidate a little more?  I don't get how i can implement this on my code.

Comment: Okay, i managed to do it. A little bit diferent, here's whats working for me :

`code this.ipClientes1.Controls.Find(panel, true)[0].Controls[statusb1].InvokeRequired code`

Thank you !

Comment: In that case you could just: `this.ipClientes1.Controls.Find(statusb1, true)[0].InvokeRequired`